# What is the best way to call a function asynchronously in a Django view?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, web

I want to call a function from a Django view, that may take 2-5 minutes to finish. I plan to call it asynchronously, return after the job is started, and poll with AJAX to wait for the FINISHED flag.

I don't want to use a heavy-weight solution like Celery+RabbitMQ, just a simple async call is fine.

How should I do it? I have read about subprocesses, threading, and twisted. Which is the best (safest) way to use in a Django view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution by far is a separate job queuing system such as Celery; there is no particularly good alternative.  This is what job queuing systems are for.  There are some lighter-weight alternatives to Celery such as RQ (Redis Queue), which uses a Redis instance as the backend and has a handy Django interface called [django-rq](https://github.com/ui/django-rq).

I strongly encourage you to use the specialized tool that solves this problem, because ad hoc solutions tend to cause complex and difficult-to-debug problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to resort to Celery+Redis or RabbitMQ, you can write a management command with your processing code. From your view, you can call your management command asynchronously with something like

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen(['manage.py', 'my_command'])
```

As someone said on another question: The Popen instance can do various other things like you can `poll()` it to see if it is still running.
I hope the popen instance you get is thread safe, or is serializable, so that you can reuse it to know if the process has finished running or not.

Comment: How can I write a test that checks if `my_command` is actually called after executing the provided code?